# How can the divs added by default by Views be removed?

Tags: theming, views

In [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), if I don't use any classes, even not the default, it still insists of wrapping the field contents into **divs**. I have had to use `views-view-fields--VIEW-ID.tpl.php` to theme the content, when it would had been very easy to tell Drupal not to warp with divs. Surely I am doing something wrong in the UI of Views, but I cannot identify what: in each field, the *Style Settings* has every checkbox unchecked, even the *"Add default classes"* checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary, you NEED to select the boxes for field, label and wrapper, and select **None** in the drop down menu. This will get rid of the `<div>`.

[image]

The **Add default classes** has nothing to do with the HTML elements - only with the css classes it adds to the tag.

Additionally you can deselect **Provide default field wrappers** under Format > Settings
[image]

**EDIT**: So, testing confirms that there are NO divs for fields anymore if you uncheck **Provide default field wrappers**. See image. Why modify a tpl file if you can do this with the interface? The only divs you see in the image are the ones that separate rows in the Unformatted list output. "See, mom, no divs!"

[image]

Comment: I see other answers that advise you to modify with the tpl file. Why??? You can do this easily with the Views UI following the directions above. The only DIVs that will be added are the ones separating rows. NO field DIVs if you uncheck "Provide default field wrapper elements" as above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is default `views-view-fields--VIEW-ID.tpl.php` template:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
    <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
    <?php print $field->content; ?>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can remove all wrappers by doing this:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
  <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
  <?php print $field->content; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or even like this:

```
<?php print $fields['FIELD_NAME']->content; ?>
```

Note that after those changes you won't have possibility to change wrappers through Views UI.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nothing wrong. Altering the view templates is the only way to get rid of the divs.

Comment: Actually, this is an answer to the question. The question is: How can the divs added by default by Views be removed? My answer is: By altering the view templates.